# How can I rerun only failed scenarios in the feature in Karate API?

Tags: automated-tests, karate, junit5

I want to rerun failed scenarios in Karate. But I dont want to run whole scenarios in the feature file with call func. If feature has failed scenarios, I dont want to rerun failed step with "retry until". So, Is there a way to rerun only failed scenarios in Karate?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835945/143475